# How to hide individual paragraph elements on jquery?

Tags: jquery

So here is my site: http://alexkchen.me/agingquestions.php

I'd like to hide the paragraph below "Where can I pursue the study of aging?" when I click "Where can I pursue the study of aging?" (but only that paragraph).

I'd like to hide the paragraph below "What is the mTOR pathway?" when I click "What is the mTOR pathway?".

(ultimately I'd also like to expand out those paragraphs if I click the headers again).

How would I do this with jquery?

Comment: One [now deleted] answer suggested "$('p').eq(5).hide();". I want the input argument in eq to be the same as the position of the p though.

Comment: Might be good to post some of your html code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?
$('h4').eq(0).on('click', function() { $('p').eq(2).hide(); });

Answer (score 1):

hi followoing jquery script i will help you do the functionality you required.

```
$("h4").click(function(){
    $(this).next('p').toggle();
});
```

Please refer following js fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/664mj0qp/

Comment: Oh cool - thanks very much! Do you know how I can do the toggle if there are multiple p elements between two h4 tags? Here's an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/664mj0qp/5/ . The toggle only works for the first p element.

Comment: @InquilineKea Oh great...Keep all p elements between two h4 tags in span with class name of toggleSpan...  I had updated js fiddle check this...                   http://jsfiddle.net/664mj0qp/6/

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$("h4").click(function() { 
  $(this).next("p").toggle();
});
```

Also, it would be a good idea to use classes to better target the elements.

Comment: Awesome - thanks - that works! What about all collapsing/expanding all the paragraphs before the next h4? (I just edited the code to insert a separate div class for each of the elements)

Comment: @InquilineKea I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly... try using `nextAll` instead of `next`.